# Bootstrap : How do i create responsive div columns in the small screens with or without media queries?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

On a small screen, div1 and div2 are showing side by side overlapped, and I want div1 content shows first and div2 content to be shown just underneath div1. How do I achieve these requirements with or without media queries?

```
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-xs-6" id="div1">
    test column1
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-6" id="div2">
    test column 2
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I believe, by default boostrap handles this and it has a very good documentation. Refer - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 4):

Update your elements' classes to this:

```
<div class="row">

 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" id="div1">
  test column1
 </div>

 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" id="div2">
  test column 2
 </div>

</div>
```

This way, at viewports >= 768px, they'll be side-by-side and at 767px & below they'll display one below the other.

As mentioned in a comment on the OP, please refer to the documentation, which covers this in greater detail: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: This works great. But the  content is not   get wrappped into next line when i reduce to smallll scrreen.  Currently content being  hidden on  small screeen.